# How to change include path for Visual Studio Conan?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, conan

I am trying to create a cross platform application (Linux/Windows), which uses third party dependencies, like `jsoncpp`. On Linux I use `cmake`, on Windows I use `Visual Studio` + `Conan`. There is a problem that the paths to cpp headers differ on different operating systems. On Linux I include jsoncpp like this:

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/config.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
```

But on Windows I have to use other ways:

```
#include <json/config.h>
#include <json/value.h>
```

On Windows, Conan installs headers along the way (there is no jsoncpp prefix):

```
C:\Users\User\.conan\data\jsoncpp\1.9.0\theirix\stable\package\3fb49604f9c2f729b85ba3115852006824e72cab\include\json
```

Content of conaninfo.txt file:

```
[requires]
jsoncpp/1.9.0@theirix/stable
[generators]
MSBuildDeps
```

There is a way to use include paths, like on Linux? Without such ugly code:

```
#ifdef __linux__
#include <jsoncpp/json/config.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
#else
#include <json/config.h>
#include <json/value.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, add an explicit include path to the compiler options to include jsoncpp, so that `#include <json/config.h>` will work there as well.

That is,

```
target_include_directories(yourprogram PRIVATE /usr/include/jsoncpp)
```

Instead, use `${JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS}` or similar if you have used CMake to locate the library for you.

But why not use Conan on Linux as well?  If you're going through the pain on Windows, you might benefit from using a single dependency management framework all over.